# Why is the voltage dropping across my parallel circuit?

Tags: voltage, parallel

I'm building something and finding an unexpected voltage (DC) drop as I get further away from the power supply. I'm convinced I have a parallel circuit, but surely if I had I'd see a drop across the whole circuit, not as the number of loads between you and the power supply increases.

To try debug this I created the very simple circuit shown. The voltage shown by the meter in the circuit is lower than if I measure it at the terminals of the power supply. I can't understand this - it's all one wire!

If I remove the load, the meter shows the same voltage as measured at the power supply. Somehow I think I must have a serial circuit, but I can't see it. Any ideas? What have I missed?

[image]

Comment: Wires & connectors both have non-zero resistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have real world wires with resistance. They are not zero ohm superconductos.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused as to why removing the load removed the voltage drop, but that's because the wires have no resistance when there is no current...

Comment: @Richard, There is always resistance but there is no voltage drop when there is no current...